# Add product_type on wcfm plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to add add *groupbuy* product type from this [plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-group-buy-and-deals/18977834?s_rank=2) on another plugin.

On admin account, it's possible to add "*groupbuy*" product with all required specific field for this product.

But, I want to allow the vendor (role provided by the [plugin WCFM](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-frontend-manager/)), to add this product, at the moment the *groupbuy* product is not available on the add panel product. Only "Simple product, Variable product, Grouped product, External product" are available.

My question is how to add this new type product (and with is dedicated form/tab to add specific field) on this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following snippet in wcfm forum so try it

```
add_filter( 'wcfm_product_types', function( $pro_types ) {
    $pro_types['new_product'] = __( 'New Product', 'woocommerce' );
    return $pro_types;
}, 50 );
```

Where new_product is the product type name and New Product is what your vendors will see as name.

Comment: Thanks, on which file I have to add this snippet?

Comment: add it in your functions.php in your theme?

Comment: Ok, this respond to a part of question, yes this add my new type, but the specific panel to this product doesn't appear.

Comment: Hmm, could be because groupbuy plugin loads before wcfm ? I would suggest contacting both plugin authors to give you the best approach.